# Rule not working in rewrite rules despite valid regex

Tags: regex, web-config, url-rewrite-module

Our webconfig file uses Url Rewrite, essentially pushing any http traffic to https

This works fine other than developing locally. For a while we have to simply remember to comment out the code from the web.config and uncomment it again for commit. Naturally this isn't a good way to work.

The code is simple

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect-AllWWW-ToSecureNonWWW">
      <match url="^((?!local).)*$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect-AllNonSecure-ToSecureNonWWW-ExcludingLocalhost">
      <match url="^((?!local).)*$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)?(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And as per the regex101 , it works!
https://regex101.com/r/3Mz6w1/1

However, when on localhost, I am still directed to HTTPS

Why does it work in regex101 and not in my web.config file

Comment: Do you need something like this? `https?:\/\/(?!.*?local).*`

Comment: What if the site is http... the link shows what I need matching?

Comment: what do you mean? What is the problem with the regex above?

Comment: Perhaps adding the end of string anchor: https://regex101.com/r/3Mz6w1/1

Comment: Sorry @CasimiretHippolyte, my question wasn't clear. Whilst I had some issues with the regex, the issue is more about why the config file's rule ignores it. I've updated my post using your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to [Redirect rule not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054732/redirect-rule-not-working)

> *quote from [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)*
>
> A rewrite rule pattern is used to specify a pattern to which the current **URL path** is compared.
>
> ...
>
> A pattern is specified within a <match> element of a rewrite rule.

According to this piece of official information, you must be sure that `<match url` compares only with **URL paths** *which never contain host names*, **not the entire URL**.

For Url Rewrite Module, URL path of this question is `questions/44944175/rule-not-working-in-rewrite-rules-despite-valid-regex` for example. No `stackoverflow.com` no `https://` no query strings but only the path without leading slash.

To ignore requests for host names containing `local` you need some conditions looking for a `local` match with `HTTP_HOST` header.

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect-AllWWW-ToSecureNonWWW" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <!-- continue if http host name does not contain "local" -->
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="local" negate="true" />

                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)(.+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect-AllNonSecure-ToSecureNonWWW-ExcludingLocalhost" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <!-- continue if http host name does not contain "local" -->
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="local" negate="true" />

                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)?(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for negate="true"